# Solving a differential inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to know the working procedure to get the solution for the following differential inequality:
$$
\frac{dx^2}{dt}\leq-ax^2+bx
$$
for $a>0, b>0$. The solution should be in the form of $x(t)\leq f(x(0), a,b)$. Sorry if this is a straightforward solution but I could not find any helpful notes on the internet.
Thanks!

Comment: Is $\dfrac{\mathrm d(x^2)}{\mathrm dt}$ or $\dfrac{\mathrm d^2x}{\mathrm dt^2}$  in the l.h.s.?

Comment: it's $\frac{d(x^2)}{dt}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$\frac{dx^2}{dt} \le -ax^2+bx \\ 2x\frac{dx}{dt} \le -ax^2+bx \\ \int \frac{2x}{ax^2-bx} \ dx \le \int - dt \\ \frac 2a \ \log |ax-b| \le -t+C_1 \\ \log|ax-b| \le \frac{-at}{2} + C_2 \\ \implies x(t)\le \frac 1a \left(C_3e^{\frac{-at}{2}} +b\right)$$

Now,  $C_3 = a x(0)-b$ and hence

$$x(t) \le \frac1a \left((ax(0)-b) \ e^{\frac{-at}{2}} + b\right)$$

Comment: You have assumed that $x>0$ in separating your variables -- in particular when dividing by $ax^2-bx.$

Comment: Also, you assumed that $\mathrm dt>0,$ although that may be admissible.

Comment: @Allawonder Right, I just realized that. Though the $\le$ sign in the OP’s post suggests making this assumption is necessary.

Comment: Why, though, is that suggested by the symbol? Couldn't you treat the other cases separately?

Comment: @Allawonder I guess what you mean is in that case we could express the solution as $x(t)\le 0=f(x(0),a,b)$?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that you should also consider the cases when $ax^2-bx\le 0.$

Comment: @Allawonder I know, I am referring to those cases.

Comment: thanks @Tavish for your answer, I think Allawonder is right in saying that I did not specify the sign of $-ax^2+bx$, so $ax^2-bx\leq0$ is also a possible case.

Comment: @wondermaster Of course it is, in which case the sign would be swapped.